# Panic during panic

Tags: go

When running an http server in Go (go1.2.1 linux/amd64) I get a rare error.

```
unexpected fault address 0xb84004
fatal error: fault
[signal 0x7 code=0x2 addr=0xb84004 pc=0x421d62]

goroutine 1 [running]:
unexpected fault address 0xacb59c
panic during panic
```

This only happened once, so far, after almost a week of running and is not reproducible. However, I would still like to know what this means and how this could happen. Unfortunately I cannot provide any code sample, since I don't know where it might occur and the code is not open source (yet), so I'm looking for a more general answer. Anyone?

Comment: This may not be relevant to the panic, but go1.2.1 is pretty old by now. I'd suggest updating.

Comment: Thanks, I might try that. But I would prefer to use the version of Go that ships with the distro on the production system. Even so I would like to know what could cause the error.

Comment: Do you have the full stack trace? It will refer to lines in your source files, and all imported libraries, at the time of the panic.

Comment: You triggered a SIGBUS somehow. Could be through a race condition, cgo, syscall, unsafe, incorrect signal handling, etc. There's nothing we can do with the information provided.  First things to do are run the race detector and update the go version.

Comment: Re. updating: I prefer software installed from packages, too. To get the best of both worlds I just periodically build backports from [official Debian package sources](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-golang/golang.git) and install those packages (actually, I first push them to a locally-maintained Debian repository). And yes, I'd say 1.5 gathered too much goodness compared to 1.2, to miss it out ;-)

Comment: Also, running Go on a production system doesn't require any Go packages. The Go package is a development tool, and current versions are often required regardless of the library versions being deployed to. Not to mention if this is on a production system, wouldn't you want a version without the known bugs, including security issues?

Comment: I think we need more information in order to debug this. But [here is some discussion on `panic during panic`](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/golang-nuts/DTVCmYrkb00) which may be of use.